# what does "not strongly connected graph" means in centiserve centroid computation?

Tags: r, igraph, network-analysis

As in the question, I have four different networks which I load from 4 different csv files. Each one fails when I compute the [centroid](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/centiserve/versions/1.0.0/topics/centroid) using [centiserve](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/centiserve/versions/1.0.0) library. On the other hand, if I generate a random ER network, the centroid computation works.

I looked into the centroid funcion and eventually I found it checks whether the network is connected using an igraph this function `is.connected(g, mode="strong")`

[According to wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strongly_connected_component) a graph is strongly connected if all the nodes are reachable from a random node in the network. To this aim, I calculated the components of my network, using igraph's `decompose()` function and all the networks have a single connected component: `length(decompose(net))` is always equal to 1. But, `centroid(net)` is always returning the error.

Eventually, the question is: What exactly is this function looking for when it verifies if the graph is suitable? Why my network has a single connected component but the `is.connected()` function of igraph return False?

Some code:

```
#load file
finalNet <- read.csv("net.csv", sep=",", header=T)
#get network
net <- graph_from_data_frame(finalNet[, c(1, 2)])
#decompose says that there is a single connected component
length(decompose(net))
#while centroid does not work!
centroid(net)
```

the network is available [here](https://pastebin.com/EaBu116v)

Comment: Can you provide a minimal reproducible example?

Comment: @Christoph working on it.

Comment: @Christoph, there you go. the not working code is now available along with the network.

Comment: Notice that `decompose` uses weak components by default. `is.connected` is checking strong components.

Comment: @G5W, yes I checked it out and the graph does not have a strong component. I'm trying to understand why.

Comment: `decompose` is actually showing 10 components, not one.  Look at `str(decompose(net))`   and `length(decompose(net)[[1]]`

Comment: @G5W I guess I got something wrong with the decompose command. Thank you for pointing it out. I also found the issue which, I suppose, it is strongly related to what you said about the number of components!

Comment: `decompose` does not support decomposing into strongly connected componets (SCCs) in the current version of igraph's R interface. This has been fixed in the C igraph library a while ago, but the R interface has not caught up. However, `is_connected` and `components` both support SCCs

Comment: @Szabolcs in the R igraph documentation page it is mentioned that you can choose between weak or strong, as parameters for the `decompose` function. Might be that is is now implemented?

Comment: @gabt You can simply try it for yourself and see an error message that it is not implemented. Of course, the whole strong/weak distinction is meaningless unless you are working with directed graphs—I hope that was clear to you.

Comment: @Szabolcs actually I haven't tried it. And, yes, I can now say that the difference is clear. Before asking this question it was not!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, I found the answer. The problem is that the function [graph_from_data_frame](https://igraph.org/r/doc/graph_from_data_frame.html) create a directed network, if not specified otherwise.

Hence, the solution to make my example work is to load the network as not directed:

```
net <- graph_from_data_frame(finalNet[, c(1, 2)], directed=F)
```